# Why it's possible to modify an element in an array in a parent scope using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I wrote this code:

```
$var = 0
$array= @(1,2,3)

function changeData(){
    $var=1
    $array[0]=100
}

changeData

Write-host $var
Write-host $array
```

When I run it I get:

> 0
>
> 100 2 3

I understand why the variable `$var` remains 0.
We cannot modify a variable in a parent scope unless we add `global` keyword as below:

```
function changeData(){
    $global:var=1
    $array[0]=100
}
```

However, I cannot understand why the `$array` changed into `@(100,2,3)`.
The `$array` is in a parent scope too. But somehow it can be changed in function `changeData()`.

Could you tell me why this difference occurs?

Comment: `$array` is not changed. It still points to the same object in the same memory location. It's like saying "I can't open a different file, so how come I can change the content of the same file?". If you tried `$array = @(100,2,3)` to rebind the *name* to a new object, it wouldn't change the parent scope. I don't know how it could work another way - imagine if the name pointed to a file in the parent scope and you called `.close()` in the nested scope, would you expect it to stay open in the parent scope? You can't reassign the variable name, but it doesn't mean variables become immutable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Your explanation could have made me understand the diffrence between reassignable and mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do: `$array[0] = 100`, it's equivalent to invoking this method to the object: `$array.SetValue(100,0)`. Invoking a method on an object will not be restricted by the scope, so this will take effect.

Note that `$array` doesn't change after the invocation, and of course, doing this inside `changeData()` won't work either: `$array = @(4, 5, 6)`

Comment: I understood why it works this way. Thank you for your answer and suggested edit.